Changed Windows PATH env variable and now many programs are no longer recognized
I messed up with Windows 10 PATH and now many programs are not recognized any longer, like for example git.exe
At system level I have the following PATH:
%SystemRoot%\system32
%SystemRoot% 
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\

but many programs are in folders like C:\Users\myaname\AppData\Local\Programs\.... and I am not sure I should be add them in the PATH, given that there are plenty of folders there.
Are there standard folders that I should include in system/user PATH environment variables?

%AppData% does not have to explicitly added to PATH. The first thing I would do is restore the default PATH variable.

On this Windows 10 PC, the User PATH has a single entry:
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

The System PATH is far longer, with a number of Intel entries specific to this PC, but the lines you likely need are:
%SystemRoot%\system32
%SystemRoot%
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\

N.B. Any error in one PATH entry invalidates all subsequent entries. For example, if the third entry is wrong, the fourth, fifth and all after are ignored.
